# how to get a property by variable in ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'das',
  bar: 'few',
  baz: '',
};
```

I want to get some value by a variable, like:

```
var x = ''; // I must assign the variable ''
```

when I get some value:

```
if (obj[x] != '') {
  //do something
}
```

I got error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ foo: string; bar: string; baz: string; }' has no index signature.
```

How to solve it?

Don't recommend me assign some default value('bar', 'foo', 'baz') to x, please, I can't do this!!!

Comment: I did not get any error from your code, can you please tell us more where exactly you got that error.

Comment: obj is of JSON object type not of array so access it like `obj[x]` causing error so access any property of obj like this `obj.foo`.

Comment: @SunnyGoel you can access object both way there's no problem in doing `obj[x]`

Comment: Closing this as [Not Reproducible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20'das'%2C%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20'few'%2C%0D%0A%20%20baz%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20''%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(obj%5Bx%5D%20!%3D%20'')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20alert(%22works%22)%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I believe that he couldn't explain his problem

Comment: @SunnyGoel This is plain vanilla JS. And *all valid JavaScript is syntactically valid TypeScript*

Comment: sorry, I got the error in ts, not js @Justcode

Comment: What is your expected value from `obj[x]`? What do you desire to get from it? This might help us understand your question. I suppose you understand that `x` is a variable and `''` is a value.

Comment: I'm so happy I don't have to do TS :D

Comment: It is also working fine in ts.

Comment: sorry, it is not an error, the error just from tslint

Answer (score 0):

you are not validating that it exists in the object in the correct way, it should be like this:

```
 if (obj[x] != undefined) {
  //do something
 }
```

Although it does not seem to be his mistake. unless you are entering the conditional when the property of the object does not exist and that is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

When you define an object literal, accessing a property that doesn't exist on it raises an error because at that point in time we know for certain it's not there.

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'das',
  bar: 'few',
  baz: '',
};

obj.x; // Error — we know for sure `x` doesn't exist in `obj`.
```

However, if you know this object will be modified in the runtime, you can tell TypeScript what it can expect it to be. If it's going to have some properties, but you don't know their names yet, you can say so by using an *index signature*.

To do so, use the built-in `Record` type. In this case `obj` is a record of `string`.

```
const obj: Record<string, string> = {
  foo: 'das',
  bar: 'few',
  baz: '',
};


obj.x; // No error — TypeScript knows `x` might exist in runtime.
```